# Selenium Time out Error

Tags: java, testing, selenium

I am using Selenium RC to test a website. But It always show following error:

```
com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleniumException: Timed out after 30000ms
```

My Sample Code is given below:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            startRC();
            testCase_RC();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception : " + e.getMessage());

        } 

    public static void startRC() {
        selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*firefox", "https://www.example.com");
        selenium.start();
    }

    public static void testCase_RC() throws Exception {
        try {
            selenium.open("/login");
            selenium.waitForPageToLoad("200000");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Message: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

It show error on open() function. I tried many solutions given on internet, but no solution works for me. Please Help, I am new for Selenium RC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `/login` page is not responding within 30 seconds -- the configured timeout of RC. You probably want to increase that timeout value with `selenium.setTimeout`

see - https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/com/thoughtworks/selenium/DefaultSelenium.html#setTimeout(java.lang.String)

In an related note, you should consider moving off of RC and to WebDriver. RC support is deprecated and will be removed in a future version of Selenium.